# My React Component not re-render when my array object properties is changed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, react-state

Hello I'm just new in React. I have a react component that shows list users. The data was from array of object.
When I fetched new data that changed the properties in object the component was not re-render. How to solve that problem ?

Here's my code :

homepage.js

```
...
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])

async function connWS() {
ws.onmessage = async function(message) {
  var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(message.data);
  console.info('Received message: ' + message.data);
        
  switch (parsedMessage.id) {
   case 'updateListUser':
   setUsers(parsedMessage.users);
  break;
}

useEffect(() => {
  async function init() {
    await connWS();
  }
  init();
}, []);

    return (
        <Layout
            isVideoCall={false}
            rightSection={
            <Users data={users} />
        </Layout>
    );
```

Users.js

```
const Users = ({data}) => {
return (
        <div className={styled.users}>
            {data.map((user) => (
                <div className={styled.userItem}>
                    {user.imageUrl ? (
                        <img src={""} alt={user.name} />
                    ) : (
                        <span style={{ backgroundColor: `#13c2c2` }}>
                            {user.shortName}
                        </span>
                    )}
                    <p>{user.name}</p>
                    {user.state ? (
                        user.state === 'REGISTERED' || 'registered' ? (
                            <p style={{ color: `#13c2c2` }}>Online</p>
                        ) : (
                            <p style={{ color: `#f5222d` }}>Offline</p>
                        )
                    ) : (
                        <p style={{ color: `#f5222d` }}>Offline</p>
                    )}
                    
                    <div className={styled.overlay}>
                        <Button
                            className={styled.callBtn}
                            type="dashed"
                            size="large"
                            icon={
                                <Icon name="call" width={24} height={24} />
                            }
                            ghost
                            onClick={() => onClickCall(user.name)}
                        >
                            Call
                        </Button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};
}
```

Here's is the example of the users data look like.

```
const users = [
        {
            name: 'Josh',
            state: 'registered'
        },
        {
            name: 'Mike',
            state: 'in_call'
        }
    ]
```

I was trying to update the status users in list where they online/offline using websocket for realtime update. When I get the data from server that only change the `state` properties, but the component is not re-render.

I was trying to resolve using different refference memory that create a new array of object using new data but i still didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I look, you are correctly using the **setUsers** function provided by the **useState** hook to update the state. This should cause a re-render of the component, however, there are a few things you might want to check.

1. Ensure that your ws connection is open and actively sending messages.
2. Ensure that in your **onmessage** handler, you are expecting a property **users** in **parsedMessage**.
3. Check if you are updating nested properties in your state.

One final note is about your conditional rendering code for the user state. The condition **user.state === 'REGISTERED' || 'registered'** will always evaluate to true because **'registered'** is a truthy value in JavaScript. You might want to change this to **'user.state==='REGISTERED' || user.state === 'registered'** for the intended behavior.

Hope this answer would give you a hint.

Comment: omg, I didn't even realize I wrote code like that, thank you very much my app is working as it should rn